# In python, is the list returned by gc.get_objects() filled with copies, or globals?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, global

I would like the constructor of one class to be able to build a list of instances of a second class that can be used later in the program, but it would only be useful if, when modifying the elements of this instance list, the global copy was being modified, and not an instance object of the first class. Are the objects returned by gc.get_objects() the actual Globals, or are they just copies?
My code:

```
class WireConnection:
    def __init__(self, name = 'genericWire', width = 1):
        self.name = name
        self.width = width
        self.data = [0 for x in range(width)]
        self.locked = False

    def WriteData(self, value, line = 0):
        if not self.locked:
            self.data[line] = value
            return True
        else: return False

    def ReadData(self, line = 0):
        return self.data[line]

class MainFrame:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):

        print "Building HIRL Table"
        self.hirlTable = []
        for wire in gc.get_objects():
            if isinstance(wire, WireConnection):
                if wire.name[0:4] == "HIRL":
                    self.hirlTable.append(wire)
```

Would this be able to fulfill my goals?

Comment: It would work. But sounds like a pretty bad idea to get this from gc.get_objects() by design, usually you do this just as a hack or for debugging.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I've read that gc.get_objects() can be a little slow, but any other method I've read of doesn't allow for the combination of dynamic expand-ability and providing global objects. Though any other methods I might have not found that you know of would be awesome!

Comment: Globals are just references. `gc.get_objects()` returns objects that are referenced *somewhere*, including those that are only referenced by global names. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here; there are better ways to keep a registry of instances that doesn't require looping over all mutable objects in your Python process.